# how to update google maps using cocoa pods.?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Hi guys I am using google maps and other libraries. I install every library using cocoapods, but when I install a library and update with command `pod install`. I am getting this error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `GoogleMaps` required by `Podfile`
- `GoogleMaps (= 1.13.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`

Specs satisfying the `GoogleMaps` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Specs satisfying the `GoogleMaps (= 1.13.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Here is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod ‘Facebook-iOS-SDK’
pod 'TwitterKit'
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4'
```

Comment: if someone face that issue please help

Comment: Did you try `pod update`?

Comment: yes sir i tried it gives same error for aft networking too.

Comment: can you show the error ...

Comment: yes sir look at this error in quotes " [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `AFNetworking (~> 3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."  this is the error if i update pod

Comment: should i update my pod file?

Comment: what is minimum deployment iOS version of your app?

Comment: currently is set it to 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your podfile like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'TwitterKit'
pod 'REFrostedViewController', '~> 2.4'
```

looks like platform: ios is changing from 8 to 6 because of redefinition