# GoogleMaps not being updated to 1.13

Tags: ios, google-maps, cocoapods

I am trying to get the latest version of GoogleMaps SDK. I use cocoapods, I tried `'pod update'`

where I had pod `'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.13'` in the podfile, but I am getting

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - `GoogleMaps (~> 1.13)` required by `Podfile`

I also tried to only place `pod GoogleMaps` in my podfile but I get an older version.

> Using GoogleMaps (1.10.3)

I also tried  `pod try GoogleMaps`

and I am getting an older version

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718468/how-to-update-google-maps-using-cocoa-pods. Also, check the Official Google docs for Maps IOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36718468/how-to-update-google-maps-using-cocoa-pods

Comment: @d.datul1990 but why is `pod try GoogleMaps` also giving me the older version ? And my podfile already has source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638711/pod-install-doesnt-update-an-existing-pod / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638711/pod-install-doesnt-update-an-existing-pod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating cocoapods using `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods` and then `pod setup` I was able to gt the latest version of GoogleMaps using `pod update` without changing anything in the podfile.